# Expect script doesn't work from cron ,works from command line

Tags: linux, cron, expect

Here the script and message observed:

```
[root@server01 ~]# cat /usr/local/scripts/rsync.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect 
eval spawn rsync -av --delete /backup/ root@server02:/backup  
;#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "welcome123\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "pwd"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
expect "#"
expect eof
[root@server01 ~]# 

expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect "#""
    (file "/usr/local/scripts/rsync.exp" line 13)
[root@server01 ~]#
```

I see above error when I kill with ctrl+d at the command line.

Comment: Is `rsync` in cron's `$PATH`? Also, you don't need to `eval spawn`, just spawn.

Comment: Sorry was away for a while .

Comment: echo $PATH
3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin
[root@server01 ~]# /usr/local/scripts/rsync.exp
spawn rsync -av --delete /backup/ root@server02:/media/neeld/500Gb-DEllB/wordpressbkup
root@server02's password: 
sending incremental file list
./
mysqldump/
sent 874 bytes  received 105 bytes  1958.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2027555856  speedup is 2071047.86
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"
    (file "/usr/local/scripts/rsync.exp" line 16)
[root@server01 ~]#